# How to connect to SSL enabled MongoDB with the PHP userland library?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm using the PHP userland library, found here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library
, with documentation at: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/classes/client/

How do I supply SSL options and which constructor to use? I'm assuming MongoDB/Client but documentation is sparse.
I have the usual on the server; CA file, server certificate and private key file with net.ssl being set to requireSSL.

So if anyone has tried anything, it'd be great if you can list what worked.

**Update**
A lot of googling took me to [this page](http://www.allanbank.com/blog/security/tls/x.509/2014/10/13/tls-x509-and-mongodb/). and I could only get the mongo shell connected successfully, but definitely not through the php library. I am using MongoDB 3.2.1 on Centos7.

Additionally I see that client certificates need two additional fields in the x509 certificates[keyUsage = digitalSignature, extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth], as narrated [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/). Now although that isn't impossible, but isn't a very manageable or scalable way for my implementation in my opinion.

Also a strange thing I discovered is that the CN in the final client certificate needs to be "localhost.". You cannot omit the last period. And the --host argument accordingly has to be "localhost." (not just localhost) or else the validation fails. But if you try to create a certificate with the CN as just localhost, you will never be able to connect to the server and the validation would fail everytime.

Comment: An easy solution would be to use [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/howto.html).

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I just don't want to introduce more moving parts and was hoping I could get this done simply. The current implementation uses a compiled 2.6 version to support SSL/TLS and the legacy php library and we have to update it, hence the situation. Thanks for the tip anyways. :)